# How to update null value'd id's with decreasing negative numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mess of a database table with many missing id's.  I want to take all the rows that have a null value instead of a number, and start increment backwards with -2, -3, -4, and so on(-1 is already used for something special).  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please give us sample tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use variables:

```
set @n = -1;

update t
    set col = (@n := @n - 1)
    where col is null;
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the first row that works on will be set to -2?  It evaulates @n-1 first and then sets the column to that ie -2?

Just tested it, thank you.

Comment: @bjk116 . . . Yes, the `-1` is subtracted first.